# Is it possible to transport multiple factories simultaneously in X: Beyond the Frontier?

Tags: x-beyond-the-frontier

In [X: Beyond the Frontier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_Beyond_the_Frontier) (note: the original, not [X-Tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X:_Beyond_the_Frontier#X-Tension)) the player can hire transport ships to carry newly bought factories from the shipyard to the location of their choice.

Considering the speed - or lack thereof - of those huge transport ships, carrying a factory through more than one or two systems becomes tedious. I was wondering if there is a way to transport more than one factories at once. I thought about hiring multiple transports on my way to the shipyard, but as far as I can tell I can still only buy one single factory - I do not seem to be able to use the other transports...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented a bit and found something useful:

When purchasing factories from the shipyard, only *one* transport ship in the sector will be used. That means that you cannot hire e.g. two ships and buy two factories at once - the second transport will not be used.

*However*, if you manage to get the ship that carries the first factory on its way to one of the next sectors by traveling there and waiting for it, you *can* quickly skip back to the shipyard, hire another TL ship and buy a second factory.

The trivial way to use this would be to bring a hired transport from another sector, use it for the first factory, get it to the next sector and then go back, quickly hire the *local* transport and buy a second factory. Timing is a bit critical, so having a docking computer should allow you enough time for your shopping spree before the first transport follows you back.

Alternatively, if you wish to bring multiple factories from different races to a location, you can select a route that goes through the shipyards and just hire the local transport in each case - under normal circumstances the other transports will be lagging behind you so the "one transport per shipyard" rule is not violated...